# Why is my angular directive not getting Parent controller scope inside isolated scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, isolate-scope

I've followed Angular docs precisely to get a directive working with an isolated scope containing a couple of vars from the parent Controller's scope object.

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Parent Name';

    $scope.pokie = {
        whyIs: "thisUndefined?"
    };
});

app.directive('parseObject', function() {

    var preLink = function($scope, el, att, controller) {
        console.log('[link] :: ', $scope);
    };

    var postLink = function($scope, el, att, controller) {
        console.log('[PostLink] :: ', $scope);
        console.log('[$Parent] :: ', $scope.$parent.name);
    };

    return {

        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            myPokie: '=pokie',
            name: '=name'
        },
        template: [
          '<div>',
          '<h1>Directive does not get parent scope</h1>',
          '<h1>{{ myPokie }}</h1>',
          '<h2>{{ name }}</h2>',
          '</div>'
        ].join(''),

        compile: function() {
            return {
                pre: preLink,
                post: postLink
            }
        }
    }
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/FpQtt9?p=preview

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code? Why does the directive's Isolate scope return undefined values for 'myPokie' and 'name'?

I've seen other people saying you have to use $scope.watch for this.. but angular's directive docs don't say anything about that.. And I really don't want to use $scope.watch for something so trivial which should work out of the box.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you declared isolated scope in your directive, that means you are going to provide those value to your directive using attribute.

```
 scope: {
     myPokie: '=pokie',
     name: '=name'
 }
```

This means your directive scope will not be prototypically inherited from the parent scope. `pokie` attribute provide the value for `myPokie` & `name` attribute will provide value of `name` for your directive, `=` indicating a two way binding if your `myPokie` value change in directive, the same referencing value will change in the parent controller. The same is true for the `name` attribute.

Your directive element markup should be:

```
<parse-object pokie="pokie" name="name"></parse-object>
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/oKSLBk?p=info)

Comment: Thanks, preferred your shorter answer :)

Comment: Is it possible to get those values from controller scope into an isolated directive scope without defining them again in the directive html code? <parse-object pokie="pokie" name="name"> feels redundant when I just want to use some vars from controller scope in the directive...

Comment: @user1383029 why you feel those variable as redundant..? you are creating a component which can placed anywhere in your app that need need certain set of values can be pass through attributes.. Suppose you have a page that has the same directive twice..how will it work.. Rather as you are asking how can I access value without passing it in isolated scope of directive, then you need to use `$parent` annotation while accessing parent scope values..

Answer (score 1):

You're using isolated scope but you're not passing the variables. The problem is in your HTML:

Change your HTML from:

```
<parse-object></parse-object>
```

To:

```
<parse-object pokie="pokie" name="name"></parse-object>
```

Isolated scope takes its parameters from the DOM element. So if you have inside the scope declaration:

```
myPokie: '=pokie',
```

That means that `myPokie` variable should be taken from the `pokie` attribute that's on the scope. Your `name: "=name"` can be changed to `name: "="` since it is exactly the same name.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/A4oQoBTOGBFgUX7xrGJd?p=preview)

Comment: I beated you by few 17 seconds :p

Comment: @pankajparkar Yes, I had to type some more :)

Comment: I'm going to type more than that..thats why I'm taking time :p

Comment: Now its bit longer than you..:p